# How can I show "No Data" message in Pie Chart when there is no data using VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I just want to display 'No Data' at the beginning. And when a user selects something with no data. I use v-if but the message not showing up and adding some javascript code but it didn't work at all. How can I achieve that using VueJS? Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my code

HTML

```html
<div class="wrapper mt-5">
  <canvas ref="myChart2" id="myChart2" v-if="myChart2 != 0" width="600" height="250" class="mb-5"></canvas>
  <span v-if="myChart2 == 0">No data</span>
</div>
```

METHODS

```
axios.post(this.urlRoot + this.api + "best_beneficiary_reports.php?barangay_id=" + this.filter_search + "&search=" + this.select_reports)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    vm.best_beneficiaries = response.data
    var ctxChart = self.$refs.myChart2.getContext('2d');

    for(var i = 0; i < this.best_beneficiaries.length; i++) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.best_beneficiaries[i].Total);
    }

    if (this.myChart2) this.myChart2.destroy();

    this.myChart2 = new Chart(ctxChart, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: vm.best_beneficiaries.map(item => item.Beneficiary),
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Total Amount',
          data: vm.best_beneficiaries.map(item => (item.Total / sum * 100).toFixed(2)),
          backgroundColor: this.poolColors(vm.best_beneficiaries.length),
          borderColor: '#eee',
          borderWidth: 2
        }]
      },
      responsive : true,
      options: {
        title: {
          display : true,
          text : "Lifetime Best Beneficiary",
          fontFamily: "sans-serif",
          fontSize: 18,
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: "single",
          callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltipItem, data) { return 'Date: ' + data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index]; },
            label: function (tooltipItems, data) { return 'Avg: ' + data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index] + "%"; } 
          },
          animation: {
            onComplete: function(animation) {
              var firstSet = animation.myChart2.config.data.datasets[0].data,
                  dataSum = firstSet.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);

              if (typeof firstSet !== "object" || dataSum === 0) {
                document.getElementById('no-data').style.display = 'block';                                     
                document.getElementById('myChart2').style.display = 'none'
              } 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `this.myChart2` is declared elsewhere and will be used to access the chart object, and I'm guessing that this property is never `== 0` so isn't a suitable test condition.

The property you are looking for is the length of the data array in the dataset `this.myChart2.data.dataset.data.length`, unfortunately this property does exist until the data is received from the server so referencing it directly will result in 'cannot read property length of undefined' errors

My suggestion would be to initalize another property in your vue component to store your data length, say `this.myChart2Length  = 0;` and update this when you get your axios response `this.myChart2Length = vm.best_beneficiaries.length || 0;`

Then in your template you can reference the new property in your `v-if` condition

```
<div class="wrapper mt-5">
  <canvas ref="myChart2" id="myChart2" v-if="myChart2Length > 0" width="600" height="250" class="mb-5"></canvas>
  <span v-else >No data</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I alert this code `this.myChart2Length = vm.best_beneficiaries.length || 0;` its give zero when I didn;t select anything. The problem is the span is not showing. I put this code after `vm.best_beneficiaries = response.data`

Comment: What happens if you just try and output the length value unto a new span `<span >{{myChart2Length}}</span>` ?